# NodeJS: Stream.pipe(Stream) works but Stream.read() doesn't

Tags: node.js, http, multipartform-data

I'm new to NodeJS and what I'm basically trying to do is to upload a .pdf to my server via HTTP. I'm using a POST rquest for that with the Content-Type multipart/form-data. In NodeJS I use [multiparty](https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty) to parse my requests.

The funny thing is, that when I want to access the form-data part of my request, which is a JSON object in my case, it works when I pipe() the the Stream that I get from multiparty to stdout but when I read() the Stream, I only get null.

This is the (probably) important part of my code:

```
form.on('part', (part) => {    // part is the Stream returned by multiparty
  if(!part.filename) {         // only fields, not files
    console.log(part.read());  // output is null
    part.pipe(process.stdout); // output is my JSON object 
    part.resume();
  }
}
```

I don't get any errors.

I'm very sorry incase I made a really dump mistake...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perheps `part` is in flow mode. You could try something like this

```
form.on('part', (part) => {    // part is the Stream returned by multiparty
  if(!part.filename) {         // only fields, not files
    part.on('data', chunk => {
      console.log(chunk.toString())
    })
    .on('error', console.error) // if stream emits errors you should handle them
  }
}
```